# Blank Page before a standalone

Tags: document-classes, standalone, blank-page

The problem is, when I'm compiling the grafic(s) as a standalone, latex inserts a blank page. By defining the documentclass as an article this doesn't happen.
(How can i fix this [and why is it happening?] I have to use standalone.) Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz] {standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1]
%       
        \tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
%       
        \coordinate (0) at (0,0);
%       
        \fill (0) circle (0.5mm) node [below=1.5mm, right=0.5mm] {$x^*$};
        %       
        \draw (0) -- (-11mm,11.5mm);    
        \draw (0) circle (16mm) node [left=4.5 mm, above=4.8mm] {$\eta$};
        %
        \coordinate (1) at (-0.5,-0.5);
        \coordinate (2) at (-2.5,-3);
        \coordinate (3) at (0,-4);
        \coordinate (4) at (3,-3.5);
        \coordinate (5) at (4.5, 0);
        \coordinate (6) at (2.5,3.5);
        \coordinate (7) at (-0.5,3.5);
        \coordinate (8) at (-2,3.5);
        \coordinate (9) at (-4,1.5);
        \coordinate (10) at (-3.2,0);
        \coordinate (11) at (-1,0);
        \coordinate (12) at (-0.2,0);
        %
        \draw [line width=0.8] (1) to [out=180,in=130] (2); 
        \draw [line width=0.8] (2) to [out=310,in=210] (3);
        \draw [line width=0.8] (3) to [out=30,in=170] (4);
        \draw [line width=0.8] (4) to [out=350,in=220] (5);
        \draw [line width=0.8] (5) to [out=40,in=290] (6);
        \draw [line width=0.8] (6) to [out=110,in=80] (7);
        \draw [line width=0.8] (7) to [out=260,in=340] (8);
        \draw [line width=0.8] (8) to [out=160,in=140] (9);
        \draw [line width=0.8] (9) to [out=320,in=170] (10);
        \draw [->-, line width=0.8] (10) to [out=350,in=140] (11);
        \draw [->-, line width=0.8] (11) to [out=320,in=180] (12);
        %       
        \fill (1) circle (0.5mm) node [right=0.5, below=0.5mm]{$x$};
%       
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use the figure environment.

Comment: Solved it perfect and way easier then i thought, thank you very much!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- i think this one is worth an answer.  although the solution was obvious to me, it probably won't be to someone using `standalone` for the first time.  so this question shouldn't be lost (unless there's already a duplicate; i haven't looked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the figure environment with the standalone class. It doesn't make sense and has the side effect to create a blank page.